# PredictFocus() not working for next

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, focus

I have created a WPF application . I need to identify Next focusable element . For that I have added following code.

```
UIElement elementWithFocus = System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
            var a = elementWithFocus.PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
```

But it is showing that Next is not supported. How I can achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to list all the controls on your window and search for the one which has it's TabIndex property equals to the current TabIndex property + 1

```
private UIElement SearchNextControl(int currentTabIndex)  
{  
    foreach (UIElement element in AllTheControls)  
    {  
        if(element.TabIndex == (currentTabIndex + 1))  
        {  
            return element;  
        }  
    }  

    return null;  
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work in TabIndex is not set